# In Emacs, how to stop nxthml to mess with my background-color?

Tags: configuration, emacs

I just started to use nxhtml, and I opened PHP file, it looks just really awful.  I usually set black background-color, but PHP/nxhtml mode, background-color is set to light blue, and I don't know how to change it.  How can I change it?  Is there any good site to learn nxhtml mode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding this line:

```
(setq mumamo-background-colors nil)
```

to your .emacs(or equivalent) will disable all background colors coming from mumamo. I personally use zen-color-theme and the combination with mumamo's background colors was simply unbearable so I disabled them altogether.

Answer (score 4):

A possibly better way is to customize mumamo-chunk-coloring. This is an integer that you can set to only color chunks with depth greater than that. Default is 0 so all chunks are colored.

Another possibility is to use mumamo-no-chunk-coloring. This is a minor mode you can turn on for a buffer to avoid chunk coloring in that particular buffer. (This is in the nXhtml menu under "nXhtml / Multiple Major Modes / Remove Chunk Colors Temporarily.)

Another solution (which I would welcome) is to include the chunk coloring in the color themes so they will not clash with them. Since I think that the coloring provides useful information for most users I think that would be the best.

(PS: If you do not use colors you can show chunk dividing hints in the margins if you want too.)

Comment: I don't use menu… but that mumamo-no-chunk-coloring works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Leo: +1...   (setq mumamo-chunck-coloring 1) in my emacs startup file for the win : )

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, this is inherited from mumamo (multiple major modes). Try customizing the "mumamo-background-chunk-major" face (`M-x customize-face mumamo-background-chunk-major RET`). Un-tick the over-ridden properties to make it inherit from your default background face.

Or for more details on mumamo display, `M-x customize-group mumamo-display RET`

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have put on my .emacs to override the blue color:

```
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(mumamo-background-chunk-major ((((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:background "white")))))
```