# Emacs nXhtml Bugging Out

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I was recently browsing around for an emacs mode for php and the like and decided to settle on nXhtml.  However, I keep getting the following error: whenever I open up an html file, the entire file is highlighted in blue.  Needless to say, this is quite the annoyance.  I figure it's probably because my html files don't have any xhtml specifications.  Looking at the nXhtml website, it seems like the mode should be able to autocomplete this information automatically for me when using the shortcut Meta-Tab.  However, when I try this, emacs spits back the following error:

---

```
  (when rngalt-complete-last-try (funcall rngalt-complete-last-try))
  (or (and lt-pos (= ... lt-pos) (or ... ... ... ...)) (when rngalt-complete-last-tr$
  (let ((lt-pos ...) xmltok-dtd) (or (and lt-pos ... ...) (when rngalt-complete-last$
  (progn (unless rng-current-schema-file-name (when ... ...)) (let (... xmltok-dtd) $
  (or (when rngalt-complete-first-try (funcall rngalt-complete-first-try)) (progn (u$
  (progn (rngalt-reapply-validation-header) (when rng-current-schema-file-name (rnga$
  (if rng-validate-mode (progn (rngalt-reapply-validation-header) (when rng-current-$
  (when rng-validate-mode (rngalt-reapply-validation-header) (when rng-current-schem$
  rngalt-complete()
  run-hook-with-args-until-success(rngalt-complete)
  nxml-complete()
  call-interactively(nxml-complete nil nil)
```

---

Now, I don't know Lisp, so this is completely foreign to me.  Anyone know what's going on here?  If it helps, I'm running emacs 23 from within OS X's Terminal window.

Edit: Sorry all, but I figured out a way around this. Apparently nXhtml automatically highlights all text for some reason, but you can turn this off using the following option: M-x customize-option RET mumamo-chunk-coloring RET; and then setting the variable to some large value. Kind of a hack, I know, but it works. Source of solution: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxhtmlOldBugs

Also, thanks to Trey for helping out with code format.

Comment: You can actually answer your own question, you don't have to edit the question with the answer.  In fact, the former is preferred as it maintains the Q&A style of the site so anybody with a similar question in the future can find this and see the answer.

Comment: What David said, plus others can upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

(Duplicate question; see link below)

This isn't nxhtml-mode specifically: mumamo (Multiple Major Modes) is a separate mechanism used by nxhtml-mode.

There are (slightly) better solutions than setting `mumamo-chunk-coloring`, if you don't want mumamo to ever set background colours.

See here: [In emacs, how to stop nxthml to mess with my background-color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042123/in-emacs-how-to-stop-nxthml-to-mess-with-my-background-color)